# Vlookup multiple columns in excel

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two data sets on different sheets that I need to combine with vlookup.

Sheet 1 has columns A to G and sheet 2 has columns A to N. Column A has data common to both.

I want to add columns G to N of sheet 2 to sheet 1.

Normally I would use `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$N$20000,7,FALSE)` and change 7 to 8 etc on the following columns (absolutes are needed to pull down the correct data to the last row).

I have tried `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$N$20000,{7,8,9,10,11,12},FALSE)` Ctrl+Shift+Enter but this doesn't work as it gives a #N/A when I drag to the adjacent columns.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your formula with `COLUMN()` to get desired result.

E.g. if data starts in column A in both sheets and you just want to get it in the same column you can use:
`=VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$N$20000,COLUMN(),FALSE)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried =vlookup(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$N$99,COLUMN(G1),FALSE) but dragging to the next column changes the first  A1 to B1 and gives the error #N/A.

Comment: Need to use absolute column reference (`$A1`), I've updated the formula.